# Comparing reddit post titles doesn't work

Tags: python

I'm making a redditbot using the PRAW function using Python. The bot itself checks if a post in a subreddit contains specific words in the title and if so, crossposts it to another subreddit. However once that occurs, the process repeats itself creating duplicate crossposts, I have tried to counteract that with the title comparison, so that it filters through already existent posts.

I'm trying to compare the strings of two separate reddit submissions. So if the titles of both submissions checked match, do not post, if they don't, then post.

The code below is inside another for loop which checks the content of the other subreddit, that code works fine, the for loop below is the one giving me problems.

The variable names e.g. realtitle and realtitle1 are storing the original title of the submission title of the 1st for loop.

Apologies for the bad code and variable naming schemes.

```
import praw
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import enchant
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

timeout = 1800.0;

def FunctionName():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(senstiveredditinfohere)
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("sub1");
    source = reddit.subreddit("sub2");

    for submission in source.new(limit=50):
        realsubmission = submission; 
        title = submission.title.lower();
        realtitle = submission.title;
        realrealtitle = realtitle + " (by X)"
        title1 = submission.title + " (by X)";

        for submission1 in subreddit.new(limit=200):

            if submission1.title == realrealtitle:
                continue;
            elif submission1.title != realrealtitle:
                if "string1" in title:
                    realsubmission.crosspost(subreddit, title=realtitle + " (by X)");
                    title="";

                    realtitle = "";
                    continue;
                elif "string2" in title:
                    realsubmission.crosspost(subreddit, title=realtitle + " (by X)");
                    title="";

                    realtitle = "";
                    continue;
                elif "string3" in title:
                    realsubmission.crosspost(subreddit, title=realtitle + " (by X)");
                    title="";

                    realtitle = "";
                    continue;
                elif "string4" in title:
                    realsubmission.crosspost(subreddit, title=realtitle + " (by X)");
                    title="";

                    realtitle = "";
                    continue;
                elif "string5" in title:
                    realsubmission.crosspost(subreddit, title=realtitle + " (by X)");
                    title="";

                    realtitle = "";
                    continue;
                else:

                    break;
            else:
                break;


FunctionName()

l = task.LoopingCall(FunctionName)
l.start(timeout)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Why 3 times elif statement with the same condition?

Comment: Hi, sorry I replaced the actual string values with "string" as placeholders. Apologies should have clarified

Comment: Why those globals?

Comment: Sorry again, ignore them, just a remnant of other troubleshooting.

Comment: Also, I don't understand, wath are you doing with variable realtitle1

Comment: Removed, was totally redundant .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic of your two nested loops is fundamentally wrong. Currently it works like this:

```
for x in first_iterable:
    for y in second_iterable:
        if x != y:
            do_something(x)
```

Try this out with a couple of `range`s as your iterables and I think you'll see how it isn't doing what you want. The `do_something(x)` call will happen *every* time the `x` and `y` values don't match, possibly many times for each `x`.

For your use case, you want it only to be run once per `x`, and only if it never matches a `y`. For that you probably want code that is more like this:

```
for x in first_iterable:
    if x not in second_iterable:
        do_something(x)
```

Another way of writing the `not in` test would be to use `all(x != y for y in second_iterable)` (which will be convenient for more complicated tests than simple inequality). This code will check *all* values in `second_iterable` before running `do_something(x)`, rather than doing it repeatedly if there are many non-matching pairs.

To put that in the terms of your current code (pruning the redundant title-related variables down to just one, and giving it a better name):

```
for submission in source.new(limit=50):
    crosspost_title = submission.title + " (by X)"
    if all(crosspost_title != other.title for other in subreddit.new(limit=200)):
        ...
```

Note that it might make your code more efficient if you move the check for your keywords (e.g. `"string1"`) to come before you check that the post has not already been crossposted. I'd suggest using `any` for that test, rather than having a whole bunch of `if` tests with identical code in them (`if any(keyword in title for keyword in ["string1", "string2", ...]):`).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the great explanation and solution. Sorted it out now and will avoid nested for loops like I tried in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In your *if* statement you're breaking the for loop if title don't match. Use continue statement instead.

```
if submission1.title == realrealtitle:
        continue; # try the next submission in subreddit.new(limit=200)
```

If title match, you want to try the next.

Two more things the last *break* is unreacheable and you're storing in *title* the lower version of *submission.title*, be sure "string1", "string2", etc... are lower too.

Comment: I tried that I think, I've updated the code if that helps + the 1st for loop.

Comment: OK removed that else statement. The strings are also in lower too. I am wracking my brain over this, I have no idea what's going on, it seems like I've tried almost everything with the two for loops to try and fix it.

Do you agree that I'm comparing the titles correctly?